# speed up pandas concat function for 40 data frames each having 1 million rows and 100 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I would like to speed up pandas `concat()` function for large data frames.

I am having 40 data frames and each data frame is having say 1 million rows and 100 columns (columns can be anything: bool, string, integer etc). We have tried running it on clusters, using `dask` etc. Result is yet to come!

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to concatenate 40 data frames of shape (1M,100) into one df, resulting in (40M,100) shape.

If this is the case, you could do something like this (written in Numpy, but idea is applicable):

```
out = np.zeros((4000000, 10))
row_size = 1000000

for i in range(40):
   out[i * row_size : i * row_size + row_size, :] = datai #ith dataframe
```